# Show full post only to loged-in users

Tags: posts, login, excerpt

Very simple question: Is it possible to show post-excerpts by default and show the full post only to logged-in users? I want to decide on a per-post-basis which posts are fully visible to everybody and which posts are only fully viewable if logged-in.

Answer (score 1):

Very simple answer.  Yes, what you're describing is possible.  :)

Comment: Fair enough. Do you have an idea on how to tackle this?

Comment: Can you show what you've tried?  There are LOTS of ways to go about it, but let's see where you've started and I can help from there

Comment: I had a look a the members plugin to try to restrict the view of posts to logged-in users. I found the `is_user_logged_in()` function. But actually I don't want to write an event hook somewhere, rather find a ready-to-use plugin, before having to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: And for the record: I know, that plugin recommendations are off-topic. It's more about the steps I have to take to get where I need to. Like: Implement password protection, add custom post type (?), ...